# Quickfix Which has higher priority: message header or sessionID?

Tags: quickfix

If i send A quickfix message using

`FIX::Session::sendToTarget(FIX::Message, FIX::SessionID)`

Then suppose in header of message:

```
sender Comp ID = s1, target CompID = t1
```

and in the SessionID variable:

```
sender Comp ID = s1, target CompID = t2
```

Will the message go to `t1` or `t2`

Comment: Is this a java question?

Comment: Is this a c++ question ?

Comment: @borisbn [It would seem so](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/_session_8cpp_source.html#l01490).

Comment: @robthewolf someone might want to send the same message instance to multiple sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will use the session ID you specify in the `sendToTarget` call. From the QF source code...

```
bool Session::sendToTarget( Message& message, const SessionID& sessionID )
throw( SessionNotFound )
{
  message.setSessionID( sessionID );
  Session* pSession = lookupSession( sessionID );
  if ( !pSession ) throw SessionNotFound();
  return pSession->send( message );
}
```

Notice that the message session ID is immediately overwritten by the sessionID passed to the function.