# quickfix create order and send to currenex

Tags: java, quickfix, quickfixj

I create:

```
quickfix.fix44.NewOrderSingle order = new quickfix.fix44.NewOrderSingle();
```

fill it:

```
    order.set(new ClOrdID(String.valueOf(orderDomain.getOrderId())));
    order.set(new Product(Product.CURRENCY));
    order.set(new TransactTime(new Date()));
    ...
```

And I need send it to currenex:

```
Session.sendToTarget(order, sessionID);
```

But I have 2 questions:

1. How can I create `sessionID`? Now I do it

   SessionID sessionID = new SessionID("FIX.4.4:INITIATOR->INITIATOR");
   But I do not understand what I did here
2. How (and where) can I configure host/user/pasword?

Comment: I think your best bet is to look at the example applications that come with the quickfix/j library.

Comment: Look at the Banzai application. If you download QuickFIX/J 1.6.3, and unzip. Then in the 1.6.3 folder, unzip `org.quickfixj-1.6.3-src.zip`. Navigate in the unzipped folder to `quickfixj-examples\banzai`. Then look at `src\main\java\quickfix\examples\banzai\Banzai.java`.

Answer (score 1):

QuickFix sessionID's are contained in a `HashSet<SessionID>` which you can get from using `i.GetSessionIDs();` for a given `IInitiator i`.

Then you can get a session instance by using `Session.LookupSession(sessionID)`

What you're doing which is manually creating a sessionID which is basically setting up the message [Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398254/quickfix-which-has-higher-priority-message-header-or-sessionid) information.